# Will foxtail palm grow in pot in unbearable heat and sun?

Tags: plant-health, palm

We live in the Caribbean and we're thinking of adding a potted foxtail palm tree to our uncovered rooftop.

The issue is that it's always hot here year-round. Right now, the temperature can be 90-100 Fahrenheit, and the sun is unbearable. Also, the air's very salty. Needless to say, almost every plant that I add to the rooftop eventually dies. So far, the only thing that survives are my cactus plants.

So this is the foxtail palm tree I'm thinking of buying: it's a pot with two foxtail palm trees (the seller says I'm getting 2 for 1). One is 4 feet high and the other 5 feet high. Here's a picture:
[image]

Is this really a foxtail palm and does it look healthy? He's asking $35 for the pot (with two palms).

Will this survive constant sun and over 90 degree temperature? I'll water it when needed.

Will it grow in a pot? I will change it to a bigger pot, but it will always live in a pot.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly seems to be a Foxtail palm; whether it will cope with the intense and constant sunlight is hard to predict. They cope very well with sun, and with salt laden breezes, but they do like humidity, so the lack of humidity might be an issue. It will certainly need watering at least once a day.

I have reservations about the two in one pot being a bonus, I don't believe it is - you will need to separate them at the root and pot them up individually, for they will not grow on well in one pot together. Separating them in this way is obviously a risk, though most plants will recover from the root damage that is caused.

Some information on growing this plant here [https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/foxtail-palm/foxtail-palm-tree.htm#:~:text=Containers%20must%20be%20large%20enough,partially%20shaded%20areas%20as%20well](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/foxtail-palm/foxtail-palm-tree.htm#:%7E:text=Containers%20must%20be%20large%20enough,partially%20shaded%20areas%20as%20well).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What did you mean that they will not grow on well in one pot? Would it make a difference if I move them to a bigger pot without separating them?

Comment: Each plant wants plenty of root room to be able to develop a good stem and leaves. In the ground these make small trees and whilst a single plant won't get as big as that in a pot, two together will be even smaller because of restricted root room. Each one will need a large pot, moving into a very large pot as it grows.